# Tensor product of two polynomials. Exercise 2 paragraph 25 from "Finite dimensional vector spaces" by Paul R. Halmos

Tags: polynomials, vector-spaces, tensor-products

I'm trying to solve exercise 2 paragraph 25 from "Finite dimensional vector spaces" by Paul R. Halmos

> Let $P_{n,m}$ be the space of all polynomials $z$ with complex coefficients, in two variables $s$ and $t$, such that either $z = 0$ or else the degree of $z(s, t)$ is $\le m - 1$ for each fixed $s$ and $\le n - 1$ for each fixed $t$. Prove that there exists an isomorphism between $P_n 
> \otimes P_m$ and $P_{n,m}$ such that the element $z$ of $P_{n,m}$ that corresponds to $x \otimes y$ ($x \in P_n$ and $y \in P_m$) is given by $z(s, t) = x(s)y(t)$

Does this mean that any polynomial of two variables can be represented as a product of two polynomials of one variable?

Comment: That doesn't sound true. What about $F(s,t)=st+t^2=t(s+t)$? You can't "split" the variables in this one.

Comment: If it were true then any array m*n, for instance image, could be compressed into m+n size. But then I do not understand what kind of isomorphism is described in the problem.

Comment: The exercise does not state that every element of $P_{n,m}$ is of the form $x(s)y(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

It means that any polynomial $z(s,t)$ can be represented as a sum of polynomials, each of the form $x(s)y(t)$.

Comment: Note: this isn't just what it means, it's actually what it says. The space $P_n \otimes P_m$ is *generated* by elements $x \otimes y$, but not every element of the tensor product is of this form. To define a linear map, it suffices to specify how it maps a generating set, and this is what Halmos has done.